# Discord.js v12 Ban Command - UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values may not be empty

Tags: javascript, discord.js, quick.db

I'm having some issues with a ban command I made, and I'm not quite sure why. Everything here looks like it works but I'm getting a lot of errors in the console every time I try to run the ban command. When you run the command it should both ban the user, send a message to the logs channel, and store the punishment info using `quick.db`. Does anybody see something I'm doing wrong?

The code:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const convertToMS = require('../lib/convertTime');
const embedStruc = require('../lib/embedStructure');
const e = require('../embeds.json');
const consola = require("consola");
const db = require("quick.db");

const validateUser = (guild, id) => {
    let userID = id;

    if (userID.indexOf('<@!') > -1) {
        userID = userID.split('<@!')[1];
        userID = userID.slice(0, -1)
    } else if (userID.indexOf('<@') > -1) {
        userID = userID.split('<@')[1];
        userID = userID.slice(0, -1)
    }

    const actualMember = guild.members.cache.get(userID);

    if (!actualMember) return false;
    return actualMember.id;
}

module.exports = {
    name: 'ban',
    description: 'Bans a user',
    alias: [],
    async execute(message, args, client, prefix, logsChannel) {
        if(!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return;
        if (args.length === 0) {
            return message.channel.send(
                new MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor(e.red)
                    .setDescription(
                        `:x: **Invalid Arguments**\n` +
                        `\`${prefix}ban [@mention/user id] (reason)\``
                    )
            ).catch();
        }

        let punishedUser = validateUser(message.guild, args[0]);
        if (!punishedUser) {
            return message.channel.send(
                new MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor(e.red)
                    .setDescription(
                        `:x: **Invalid User**`
                    )
            ).catch();
        }

        let reason = 'No reason provided';
        if (args.length > 1) {
            let tempArgs = args.join(' ').split(' ');
            await tempArgs.shift();
            await tempArgs.shift();
            reason = tempArgs.join(' ');
        }

        const bannedUser = message.guild.members.cache.get(punishedUser);
        const banID = db.add(`${message.guild.id}.base`, 1).base;

        if (!bannedUser.bannable) {
            return message.channel.send(
                new MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor(e.red)
                    .setDescription(`:x: Unable to ban <@!${bannedUser.id}>.`)
            );
        }

        await bannedUser.send(
            embedStruc.userBan(
                reason,
                message.guild.name,
                banID
            )
        ).catch(() => {});

        await bannedUser.ban(`Banned for "${reason}" by ${message.author.tag}`)
            .catch(() => {
                return message.channel.send(
                    new MessageEmbed()
                        .setColor(e.red)
                        .setDescription(`:x: Unable to ban <@!${bannedUser.id}>.`)
                );
            });

        message.channel.send(
            new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor(e.default)
                .setDescription(
                    `:scream: <@!${bannedUser.id}> was banned.`
                )
        ).catch();

        logsChannel.send(
            embedStruc.logsBan(
                bannedUser.id,
                message.author.id,
                reason,
                Date.now(),
                banID
            )
        ).catch();

        db.set(`${message.guild.id}.punishments.${banID}`, {
            user: bannedUser.id,
            moderator: message.author.id,
            reason,
            time: Date.now(),
            ID: banID,
            type: "BAN"
        });

        db.push(`${message.guild.id}.${bannedUser.id}.punishments`, banID);
    },
};
```

Error:

```
(node:23906) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values may not be empty.
    at Function.normalizeField (/Users/evandeede/Downloads/modbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:432:23)
    at /Users/evandeede/Downloads/modbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:452:14
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.normalizeFields (/Users/evandeede/Downloads/modbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:451:8)
    at MessageEmbed.addFields (/Users/evandeede/Downloads/modbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:266:42)
    at MessageEmbed.addField (/Users/evandeede/Downloads/modbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:257:17)
    at Object.logsBan (/Users/evandeede/Downloads/modbot/lib/embedStructure.js:163:10)
    at Object.execute (/Users/evandeede/Downloads/modbot/commands/ban.js:98:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:23906) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:23906) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Could you please include the errors you get in your question?

Comment: it is extremely hard to debug any errors without the errors - please consider that

Comment: Sorry about that, I just added in the error message now

Comment: Looks like you're missing `values` in an embed, so it would effectively create an empty field, which is not possible. Debug your code and look for `undefined` variables in your embeds

Comment: This appears to be an issue with either one value you use being undefined, or an issue in the `../lib/embedStructure` file. Check your variables you pass to the function on line 93 are defined correctly, if they are then give us the `embedStructure` file.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from your current error, your ban function will not work:

```
await bannedUser.ban(`Banned for "${reason}" by ${message.author.tag}`)
```

You will have to put the reason in as an object, since your able to put in an amount of days too, as shown in the docs [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban)

```
await bannedUser.ban({ reason: `Banned for "${reason}" by ${message.author.tag}` })
```